# Combination of Left alignment and Rotate messes up Automatic PlotRange

Tags: plotting, graphics, text

In the following code, left-aligning the inset AND rotating it seems to completely mess up the Automatic PlotRange. Is this intended behavior? If it's a bug, is there a workaround?

12.1.0.0 on MacOS

```
good1 = Graphics[{ Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Rotate[Inset[Style["Hi", FontSize -> 50], {0, 0}, Center], 0.5] }];
good2 = Graphics[{ Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Rotate[Inset[Style["Hi", FontSize -> 50], {0, 0}, Left],   0  ] }];
bad   = Graphics[{ Circle[{0, 0}, 1], Rotate[Inset[Style["Hi", FontSize -> 50], {0, 0}, Left],   0.5] }];
{good1, good2, bad}
```

[image]